# This task requires "all conditions to be met" or "that all conditions are met"?

Tags: phrase-request

This text is a "hint" that is shown for a task in a task management app.
I want to indicate to a user that this specific task is only created when all conditions from a list are satisfied. 
Please help me to put it in a grammatically correct way.

Comment: The first one seems ok, only without "to".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the phrases "this task requires" and "is only created" somewhat elliptical. What is it about the task that requires those conditions to be met?  Can the task not be *performed* or *executed* until those conditions are met? Can the task not be *scheduled* until those conditions are met? Can the task not be *created* until those conditions are met? If **created** is what you want, then "created" could be put in the blanks here:

> All conditions on the list must be met before this task can be _____.
>
> This task cannot be _______ until all conditions on the list have been
>    met.

Is the task explicitly (i.e. manually) created by the user only after those conditions are met? Or is the task automatically created by the app when those conditions are met?

If the user creates the task manually, then the active voice would be preferable if there are other tasks which do get created automatically:

> All conditions on the list must be met before you can _________ this task.
>
> You cannot  _______  this task until all conditions on the list have been
>    met.

Comment: Thanks for putting effort in this. The app logic is that conditions are here to indicate when task is necessary at all. Otherwise it will be skipped / not created. Example: "CFO Approval" task is only needed when "Purchase amount" is more than $10,000.

Comment: I think you mean to say "allowed" or "permissible", not "necessary".  A task may have prerequisites, but when those prequisites are met, the task does not necessarily become obligatory.